# MySQL doesn't set a default value while adding a new row to the table

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, hibernate, registration

I'm writing a web application (that represents online banking work). I have an entity "user" and a corresponding table in the database. Also, I have a registration form that transfers entered data via Thymeleaf.

My entity has two rows that have default values in the database. These are "role" row and "status". I set the default value in the database.

But, when I do input data in the registration form and click "sign up", the data transfers to the database successfully, however, two rows (role and status) that have their own default values are of a null type. Why the default values aren't being set automatically?

My entity class:

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;
    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;
    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;
    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;
    @Enumerated(value = EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "status")
    private Status status;
    @Enumerated(value = EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "role")
    private Role role;
}
```

My settings in the database table:

[image]

When I check the property "NOT NULL", I'm receiving an error that tells me that the row "role" cannot be null.

That's how my table looks like when I register new users:

[image]

My controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/auth")
public class AuthController {

    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    public AuthController(UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    @GetMapping("/login")
    public String login() {
        return "/auth/login";
    }

    @GetMapping("/signup")
    public String signUp(User user, Model model) {
        return "/auth/registration";
    }

    @PostMapping("/signup")
    public String signUpProcess(@ModelAttribute User user, BindingResult bindingResult) {

        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            return "redirect:/auth/registration";
        }

        PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder(12);
        user.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()));

        userRepository.save(user);

        return "redirect:/auth/login";
    }

}
```

Registration page:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>Registration</title>

    <!-- This style must be at the top -->
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/login.css">
</head>
<body>
    <form class="form-signin" th:method="post" th:object="${user}"> <!-- added th:method and th:object -->
        <div class="text-center mb-4">
            <img class="mb-4" src="/static/images/login/codelib_logo.png" alt="" width="72" height="72">
            <h1 class="h3 mb-3 font-weight-normal">Registration</h1>
            <p> Enter all the required information into the forms below. </p>
        </div>

        <div class="form-label-group">
            <input type="text" id="inputFirstName" th:field="*{firstName}" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name" required>
            <label for="inputFirstName">First Name</label>
        </div>

        <div class="form-label-group">
            <input type="text" id="inputLastName" th:field="*{lastName}" class="form-control" placeholder="Last Name" required>
            <label for="inputLastName">Last Name</label>
        </div>

        <div class="form-label-group">
            <input type="email" id="inputEmail" th:field="*{email}" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required autofocus>
            <label for="inputEmail">Email address</label>
        </div>

        <div class="form-label-group">
            <input type="password" id="inputPassword" th:field="*{password}" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
            <label for="inputPassword">Password</label>
        </div>

        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign up</button>
        <br>
        <p>Already registered? <a href="/auth/login">Click to sign in</a></p>
        <p class="mt-5 mb-3 text-muted text-center">&copy; BlackBank 2022</p>
    </form>

    <!-- Scripts related to Bootstrap -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

If I haven't specified some valuable information, please, let me know.

Update:

SHOW CREATE TABLE:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` bigint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `first_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `role` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'USER',
  `status` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'ACTIVE',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `users_id_uindex` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

My Role and Status classes (enums):

Role.class:

```
public enum Role {
    // Each role has a specific set of permissions
    USER(Set.of(Permission.USERS_READ)),
    ADMIN(Set.of(Permission.USERS_READ, Permission.USERS_WRITE, Permission.USERS_UPDATE)),
    OWNER(Set.of(Permission.USERS_READ, Permission.USERS_WRITE, Permission.USERS_UPDATE, Permission.USERS_DELETE));

    private Set<Permission> permissions;

    Role(Set<Permission> permissions) {
        this.permissions = permissions;
    }

    public Set<Permission> getPermissions() {
        return permissions;
    }

    public Set<SimpleGrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return getPermissions().stream().map(permission -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority(permission.getPermission())).collect(Collectors.toSet());
    }

}
```

Status.class:

```
public enum Status {
    ACTIVE, BANNED;
}
```

Comment: For clarity, please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` so we can see the declared defaults.

Comment: @RickJames, updated my question, now you can see the output of SHOW CREATE TABLE, and also Status and Role classes definitions. Check it out, please

Comment: Also, please provide the generated `INSERT` SQL statement.

Answer (score 0):

@cloumn annotation should be something like below

```
@Column(name = "status", nullable=false, length = 20, columnDefinition = "varchar(20) default 'ACTIVE'")
@Column(name = "role", nullable=false, length = 20, columnDefinition = "varchar(20) default 'USER'")
```

Answer (score 0):

1. `DEFAULT` constraint defined on table will work in case of native query(in hibernate).

`"INSERT INTO USERS (id, first_name, last_name, email, password) VALUES (v1, v2,  v3, v5)"` --  **// in this case the fields(status, role) are not specified and
the db will set default value(ACTIVE, USER)**

2. another solution would be use annotation `@PrePersist` in your entity class to check the value of the fields and change it if is null(before object is saved).

   ```
     @PrePersist
     public void control() {
       if (status == null)
         setStatus("ACTIVE");
     }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Since the entity getting persisted has null values for those 2 fields it will override the specified defaults.
You can apply 3 approaches

- Assign default value in Entity class directly (can be overriden by entity setter)

  ```
  private Role role = Roles.user;
  ```
- Use Life cycle call back annotation @Prepersist/@PreUpdate (Most recommended, will override any existing value, can be used to perform logic also.)
- As suggested by Amir use attribute "columnDefinition" (can be overriden by entity setter)